# Angular 14 application save method not working properly

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have created a .net core API application and tried to parse values to SQL Server using the Angular 14 application.

**add-employee.component.ts**

```
addEmployee(){
this.employeeService.addEmployee(this.addEmployeeRequest)
.subscribe({
  next: (employee) => {
    console.log(employee);
  }
});
```

}

**employees.service.ts**

```
 addEmployee(addemployeeRequest: Employee):Observable<Employee>{
  addemployeeRequest.id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000';
   return this.http.post<Employee>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employees',
  addemployeeRequest);}
```

**EmployeesController**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([FromBody] Employee employeeRequest)
    {
        employeeRequest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        await _fullStackDbContext.Employees.AddAsync(employeeRequest);
        await _fullStackDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(employeeRequest);
    }
```

above method, I have applied with the angular application, But when I try to save values there is an error occurs with the console.

Error:
[image]
How to solve that issue?

Comment: can you share what  this.addEmployeeRequest  method returns

Comment: @Eyayu Tefera
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([FromBody] Employee employeeRequest)
        {
            employeeRequest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            await _fullStackDbContext.Employees.AddAsync(employeeRequest);
            await _fullStackDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(employeeRequest);
        }

Comment: Your browser cannot connect to the backend. As you can see the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error is thrown. It's not an issue with Angular, it could be that the backend is not running under the given URL. Did you check this with Postman? Please add enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ JSON Derulo, yes I have checked using Swagger

Comment: one more question, is your API serving with HTTPS if not you should change your end point to HTTP on angular side

Comment: @ Eyayu Tefera. Yes API Serving with HTTPS.The GET method working properly.but only post method have the issue